# Windows Process Activation / Windows Service

Tags: wpas

I currently have a WCF service hosted in IIS and using WPAS to send messages from MSMQ to it. I would like to host the service in a windows service. Will WPAS still send messages to it when it is hosted as a windows service?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. WPAS is integrated and work with IIS. If you host your service in Windows Service, then OS will be responsible for starting and stopping your service. But if you want additional functionality, you have to add code for it